# How to read_csv in Pandas without losing precision on Int64?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say we are trying to read in this csv file

```py
import io
import pandas as pd

unprocessed_file_contents = """name,impressions,spend_usd
Bob,32,76
Charlie,16,48
Mike,,
Joao,167289225369306298,"""
pandas_dtypes = {
    "name": "string",
    "impressions": "Int64",
    "spend_usd": "float",
}
```

If we read it normally, pandas converts the `167289225369306298` -> float -> Int, causing it to lose precision and become `167289225369306304`

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(unprocessed_file_contents), dtype=pandas_dtypes)
assert df.iloc[3,1] == 167289225369306298  # this fails (and becomes 167289225369306304)
```

If we read it using this method, the first assert passes, but the second fails

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(unprocessed_file_contents), header=None, skiprows=1, dtype=pandas_dtypes)
assert df.iloc[3,1] == 167289225369306298  # passes (because it compares it as a pandas type)
assert int(df.iloc[3,1]) == 167289225369306298  # fails (and becomes 167289225369306304)
```

How can we get pandas to respect `167289225369306298` as an integer during `read_csv`?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like this problem is caused by having NaN or empty values in the column.

By getting rid of those empty values it begins to work expectedly.

```
import io
import pandas as pd

unprocessed_file_contents = """name,impressions,spend_usd
Bob,32,76
Charlie,16,48
Mike,42324,
Joao,167289225369306298,"""

pandas_dtypes = {
    "name": "string",
    "impressions": "Int64",
    "spend_usd": "float",
}

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(unprocessed_file_contents), dtype=pandas_dtypes)
assert df.iloc[3,1] == 167289225369306298  # passes
```

There is also a bug report for this,

[Int64 with null value mangles large-ish integers](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/30268)

Comment: Unfortunately we still need the NULL numbers to be included....